# HTML Positioning using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with HTML positioning. I messed around for a while and this was the farthest I got. Here is the HTML and CSS

```css
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
article {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#tip,
#title {
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#tip {
  background: yellow;
}
#title {
  background: orange;
}
#box_1 {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: pink;
}
#box_2 {
  float: right;
  width: 60px;
  height: 120px;
  background: blue;
}
#box_3 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<article class="group">
  <h2 id="tip">tip</h2>
  <h2 id="title">title</h2>
  <div id="box_1"></div>
  <div id="box_3"></div>
  <div id="box_2"></div>
</article>
```

I want my `#box_3` to be right below `#box_1` and I got it to work by giving `#box_3 clear: left;`. But I also want my `#box_2` to be rendered right below `#title` on the right.

Something to note is that the `#box_3` comes before `#box_2` in my HTML code and the height of `#box_1` is not fixed to just `60px`. Here is my jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/92um5o2c/2/

Comment: is it necessary to do it with float only?

Comment: no. i used floats because the actual problem I'm having with this example is that `#box_1` can have different heights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you suffle your html code little bit so its not a problem. You should place `#box1` first then `#box2` and then `#box3`

Here is the example

```css
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

article {
    width: 400px;  
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#tip, #title{
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#tip {
    background: yellow;
}

#title {
    background: orange;
}

#box_1 { 
 float: left;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 background: pink;
}
#box_2 { 
 float: right;
 width: 60px;
 height: 120px;
 background: blue;
}
#box_3 { 
 float: left;
    clear: left;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<article class="group">
    <h2 id="tip">tip</h2>
    <h2 id="title">title</h2>
    <div id="box_1"></div>
   
    <div id="box_2"></div>
    <div id="box_3"></div>
 </article>
```

Comment: my site actually renders `#box_1` then `#box_3` first. it will only render `#box_2` after under a certain condition. so the order cannot be changed. also the height of `#box_1` is not fixed to 60px.

Comment: so if your site render `#box1` then `#box3` you can add these 2 boxes in a parent div and `#box2` will left out of it like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/92um5o2c/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the height of the boxes is fixed and will not grow, you can simply give #box_2 a negative margin which equals the height of box_1:

```
#box_2 { 
    float: right;
    width: 60px;
    height: 120px;
    background: blue;
    margin-top:-60px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/92um5o2c/4/

Comment: `margin-top:-60px` will be disadvantage if height of the elements changes its not a full proof thing.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I said "Assuming the height of the boxes is fixed and will not grow" :-)  It's a solid solution *if* that's the case.  If not, he'll have to solve this some other way.

Comment: the trouble i'm having is the fact that the height of the `#box_1` is not fixed. sorry for being unclear. also `#box_3` will always come before `#box_2`. changing the order of the HTML code isn't an option.

Comment: Ok, but what about the source order?  Does the HTML have to be exactly as it is now?

Comment: yes, `#box_3` will always come before `#box_2`. my site actually renders `#box_1` then `#box_3` first. it will only render `#box_2` after under a certain condition.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this right? Just change the order in the HTML like below.

```
    <div id="box_1"></div>
    <div id="box_2"></div>
    <div id="box_3"></div>


    #box_1 {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: pink;
}

    #box_2 {
        float: right;
        width: 60px;
        height: 120px;
        background: blue;
    }

    #box_3 {
        clear: left;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        background: green;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xn0pL6mn/

Comment: posting an answer again as it is it posted earlier is a great thing might be to earn something but not ethically good

Comment: Oh I'm sorry mate, was making the Fiddle and didn't see that anyone else had posted something already. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "position: absolute;" and "right: 0;" to #box_2 and then "position: relative;" to article.

```
#box_2 {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
}
article {
        position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/92um5o2c/9/